# Value default with thymleaf in a combobox

Tags: html, winforms, combobox, frontend, thymeleaf

I have a problem with thymleaf. I have a form with a combobox and some fields. I want put default value in the combobox and the clausure "selected" not working for me.

The code is this:

```
<select class="dsp-inline form-control" th:field="*{tipoDocumento}" required="required" th:disabled="${permisoXestion == false}">
      <option value="" th:text="#{select.option.default}"> </option>
      <option th:each="row : ${tipoDocumento}" th:value="${row}" th:text="#{${row.value}}" th:selected="#{${row==2}}"></option>
</select>
```

Where "tipoDocumento" is a enum with two values:

```
public enum TipoDocumento {
 PUBLICO("documento.tipo.publico"),
 PRIVADO("documento.tipo.privado");

private String property;

private String value;

private TipoDocumento(String property) {

    this(property, null);

    }

private TipoDocumento(String value, String property) {
   this.value = value;
   this.property = property;

}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getProperty() {
    return property;
}

public void setProperty(String property) {
    this.property = property;
}
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected tag should work. Remember it need to be added like `selected="selected"`. I have used it on several selects and it always work. Also, in your `th:each` you need to remove the `th:selected="#{${row==2}}"` element, otherwise your first option won't be the default one.

```
<select class="dsp-inline form-control" required="required" th:disabled="${permisoXestion == false}">
      <option value="" th:text="#{select.option.default}"></option>
      <option th:each="row, iter : ${tipoDocumento}" th:value="${row}" th:text="#{${row.value}}" th:selected="${iter.count eq 2} ? 'selected' : 'false'"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: I want that default value will be value of list tipoDocumento.

Comment: So what you want is your default value to starts as the selected value? Or one of the items of the list of tipoDoccumento?

Comment: I want one of the items of the list of tipoDoccumento how default value selected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perfect! Any value in particular, or I can choose which I want?

Comment: The value in second position of list, if it is possible.

Comment: Made the changes for you! It should work now like you wanted. :)

Comment: I add some changes your answer and this working for me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw your edit! I added a `th:field` that was not intended! Good to know I was of help! If you don't mind voting up as well! Those extra ten points are a wonder :).

Comment: Thanks for you. If you don't mind voting up as well too!

Comment: Just did :). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if you use the th:selected you cannot not use the th:field. You have to replace it with a name attribute.
So, can you replace

```
<select class="dsp-inline form-control" th:field="*{tipoDocumento}" required="required" th:disabled="${permisoXestion == false}">
```

with

```
 <select class="dsp-inline form-control" name="tipoDocumento" required="required" th:disabled="${permisoXestion == false}">
```

Also, the condition of the th:selected
can you replace

```
th:selected="#{${row==2}}"
```

with

```
th:selected="${row==2}"
```